# Parsing using beautifulsoup to get exact word

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the desired word using beautifulsoup. For my application, I used the arxiv API to get total numbers of related papers search. For my query, I used **electron** for search. API return about 144055 as a total search result. I want to extract this total number.

```
import urllib.request as ur
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://export.arxiv.org/api/query?search_query=all:electron' # arxiv:api
s = ur.urlopen(url)
sl = s.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(sl, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify('latin-1'))
desire_word=soup.find('opensearch:totalresults')
print(desire_word)
```

I print the desire word. But I came as whole text.

```
<opensearch:totalresults xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">144055</opensearch:totalresults>
```

How can I only get the total number (144055)?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were close

```
print(desire_word.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not enough reputation to comment, but something to note when you come across a situation where you're not sure what is being returned:

```
print(type(desire_word))
print(dir(desire_word))
```

That way you'll be able to see that

1) desire_word is not a string, it is an element

2) desire_word has an attribute named "text" and "that sounds useful, let me try `desire_word.text`"